# Why can I initialize string literal as const char* and QString but not QString*?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

I am relatively new to qt and C++, and I am having trouble understanding why I can declare the following in a header file:

```
const char* CONSIGNMENT_TAG_DONATE = "DTag";
```

or

```
QString CONSIGNMENT_TAG_DONATE = "DTag";
```

or

```
const QString CONSIGNMENT_TAG_DONATE = "DTag";
```

But when I try to use QString*

```
QString* CONSIGNMENT_TAG_DONATE = "DTag";
```

or

```
const QString* CONSIGNMENT_TAG_DONATE = "DTag";
```

I get an error saying `cannot initialize a member subobject of type 'QString*' with an lvalue of type 'const char[5]'` .  It's my understanding that string literals are of a type `const char*` so I get why that works.  But why is assigning it to `QString` valid but `QString*` not valid?  I'm sure this is a fairly basic concept of C++, I am just trying to understand it.

Comment: What is that even supposed to do? Besides, a string literal is an array of char, not a `const char*`. But most of the time, that does not really matter as the former can decay into the latter.

Comment: You don't ever need to use `QString *`... ever! ;)

Comment: without wishing to be too direct, you probably ought to read a book on c++.

Comment: Copy constructors, implicit conversions - read about those

Comment: @RichardHodges Thanks for noticing, but I am reading a 1200 page book on C++ right now.  I tried to search it for the relevant information but was unable to glean it out of the text or much googling.

Comment: @ce_nort `QString` is a container class, and container classes in Qt are implicitly shared, copy or write. If you read on the subject you will realize the basic fundamental intent of their design is to be used as values. You could use `QString &`, but `QString *` simply makes NO SENSE.

Comment: @ddriver Perfect, thank you!

Comment: In any case, this question wouldn't arise if you wouldn't initialize the string with a C literal: you're not supposed to! Use `QStringLiteral` instead. `const QString foo = QStringLiteral("abcde");`.

Comment: @KubaOber How is that `QStringLiteral` stuff better than the normal string literal?

Comment: @BaummitAugen As it says in the docs, `QStringLiteral` automatically resolves string encoding issues for you.

Comment: @BaummitAugen `QStringLiteral` constructs the `QString` representation at compile time. It saves runtime.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `QString*` is a pointer to `QString`. That means it can hold the address of a `QString` object. You cannot (or at least are not supposed to most of the time) store addresses of non-`QString` in a `QString*`.

```
const char* CONSIGNMENT_TAG_DONATE = "DTag";
```

works because the `"DTag"` (which is of type `const char[5]`) decays to `const char*`, thus the assignment makes sense.

```
QString CONSIGNMENT_TAG_DONATE = "DTag";
```

works because `QString`s have a non-explicit constructor taking `const char*`, so the literal can again decay to `const char*` which is then used to construct the `QString`.

```
QString* CONSIGNMENT_TAG_DONATE = "DTag";
```

is just nonsense, see first paragraph.

Using a `QString*` instead of a plain `QString` is most likely not helpful for your usecase.

Answer (score 1):

C++ doesn't know how to convert a char array to a pointer to `QString`.

`const char* CONSIGNMENT_TAG_DONATE = "DTag";`

Constant char array  to `const char *`- permitted

`QString CONSIGNMENT_TAG_DONATE = "DTag";`

Implicit conversion using the `QString::QString(const char *str)` constructor

`QString* CONSIGNMENT_TAG_DONATE = "DTag";`

Constant char array to `QString *` - how does this work? There are no rules to make such a conversion. It may be simple enough conceptually, but without the actual code to enable it, it will not work.

Comment: Thank you, I had been using QString more like a type than a container class and not realizing the mistake in my basic understanding of that until now.

Answer (score -1):

Update in 2023:  use QStringLiteral:

```
QString CONSIGNMENT_TAG_DONATE = QStringLiteral("DTag");
```

More details [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48013906/680353).